# XML schema namespace- Getting validation error

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I'm trying to validate an XML file against a schema.  I'm very much new at this but I'm almost 100% it has to do with the namespace.  Problem is, namespaces confuse me :/.   Can someone explain how to set it so that it will validate?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tvGuide xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="tvguide.xsd">
    <Provider TimeZone="central">      
        <ProviderName>Cox Communications</ProviderName>
        <State>NE</State>
    </Provider>
    <ListingDetails>
        <ShowName>American Horror Story</ShowName>
        <category>Drama</category>
        <HD>true</HD>
        <Rating>TV-MA</Rating>
        <New>false</New>   
        <EpisodeNumber>37</EpisodeNumber>
        <Season>5</Season>
        <Date>2016-07-25</Date>
        <EpisodeDesc>Insert Episode Description Here</EpisodeDesc>
        <Audio>Stereo</Audio>
        <ClosedCaption>true</ClosedCaption>
    </ListingDetails>
    <ChannelDetails>
        <ChannelName>FX</ChannelName>
        <ChannelDescription>Channel Description Here</ChannelDescription>
        <ChannelLogo>Channel Logo Here</ChannelLogo>
    </ChannelDetails>
    <Provider TimeZone="central">      
        <ProviderName>Cox Communications</ProviderName>
        <State>NE</State>
    </Provider>
    <ListingDetails>
        <ShowName>The Arctic Circle</ShowName>
        <category>Documentary</category>
        <HD>false</HD>
        <Rating>TV-G</Rating>
        <New>true</New>   
        <EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber>
        <Season>0</Season>
        <Date>2016-07-25</Date>
        <EpisodeDesc>This documentary takes viewers on an expedition to the Arctic Cirlee</EpisodeDesc>
        <Audio>Stereo</Audio>
        <ClosedCaption>true</ClosedCaption>
    </ListingDetails>
    <ChannelDetails>
        <ChannelName>NatGeo</ChannelName>
        <ChannelDescription>Educational</ChannelDescription>
        <ChannelLogo>Channel Logo Here</ChannelLogo>
    </ChannelDetails>
    <Provider TimeZone="central">      
        <ProviderName>Cox Communications</ProviderName>
        <State>NE</State>
    </Provider>
    <ListingDetails>
        <ShowName>Dick Van Dyke</ShowName>
        <category>Classic Family</category>
        <HD>true</HD>
        <Rating>TV-G</Rating>
        <New>false</New>   
        <EpisodeNumber>12</EpisodeNumber>
        <Season>1</Season>
        <Date>2016-07-25</Date>
        <EpisodeDesc>This is a classic episode of Dick Van Dyke.</EpisodeDesc>
        <Audio>Stereo</Audio>
        <ClosedCaption>true</ClosedCaption>
    </ListingDetails>
    <ChannelDetails>
        <ChannelName>Nick at Nite</ChannelName>
        <ChannelDescription>Classic TV</ChannelDescription>
        <ChannelLogo>Channel Logo Here</ChannelLogo>
    </ChannelDetails>
</tvGuide>
```

and my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">


        <xs:element name="tvGuide">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Provider"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ProviderName" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:attribute name="TimeZone" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
               <xs:element name="ListingDetails" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
              <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                         <xs:element name="ShowName" type="xs:string"/>
                         <xs:element name="category" type="xs:string"/>
                         <xs:element name="HD" type="xs:boolean"/>
                         <xs:element name="Rating" type="xs:string"/>
                         <xs:element name="New" type="xs:boolean"/>
                         <xs:element name="EpisodeNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
                         <xs:element name="Season" type="xs:integer"/>
                         <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
                         <xs:element name="EpisodeDesc" type="xs:string"/>
                         <xs:element name="Audio" type="xs:string"/>
                         <xs:element name="ClosedCaption" type="xs:boolean"/>
                  </xs:sequence>

              </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="ChannelDetails" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ChannelName" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="ChannelDescription" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="ChannelLogo" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
     </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema specifies vc:minVersion="1.1". It doesn't use any XSD 1.1 features, so try removing this attribute or setting it to 1.0.

I was able to reproduce the problem by running your validation using Saxon without enabling -xsdversion:1.1. In this case you are running Saxon as a 1.0 processor, and a 1.0 processor (if it recognizes vc:minVersion at all) will skip parts of the schema that require 1.1.

So the other way forward is to run Saxon with -xsdversion:1.1.

Validation still fails, with:

```
Validation error on line 27 column 34 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: In content of element <tvGuide>: The content model does not allow element
  <Provider> to appear immediately after element <ChannelDetails>. Expected <ChannelDetails>
  or nothing.
```

but that's a legitimate error: if you want the sequence (Provider, ListingDetails,ChannelDetails) to be repeatable, then your first `xs:sequence` element should be given a `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute.